# вывод формы комментариев для каждого поста и сохранение id поста

Tags: javascript, php

В общем в форме добавления комментариев input берет id только первого поста. И если я нажимаю кнопку Add Comment форма ввода выходит только для первого поста, я же хочу что бы эта форма выходила для каждого поста и бралa id именно этого поста. Как это сделать?

```
<body>

        <div class="container">
            <button type="btn" class="btn btn-primary" name="post" onclick="myFunction()">Add Post</button>
        </div>


        <div class="container" id="myDIV">
            <form action="" method="post" class="form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                <br>
                <textarea name="text" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="post">Add Post</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <?php

        foreach ($items as $col) { ?>
            <div class="container border border-success">
                <p><?= $col['name']; ?></p>
                <?= $col['text']; ?>
                <?= $col['date']; ?>
                <button type="btn" class="btn btn-primary" name="comment" onclick="showHide()">Add Comment</button>

                <div class="container">
                    <?php
                    $str = (string)$col['id'];
                    echo $str;
                    $comm = $post->get_all_comments($conn, $str);
                    foreach ($comm as $row) {
                    ?>
                        <div class="container border border-danger">
                            <h5><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h3>
                                <p><?php echo $row['text']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    <?php }  ?>

                    <div class="container" id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
                        <br>
                        <form action="" method="post" class="form">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="com_name" placeholder="Name">
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" value="<?= $col['id'] ?> ">

                            <br>
                            <textarea name="com_text" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            <br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="post_comment">Post Comment</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        <?php } ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
            if (x.style.display === "block") {
                x.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        function showHide() {
            document.getElementById("hidden_div").style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>

    </body>
```

Comment: У вас в цикле прописан `id="hidden_div"`, что означает появление на станице нескольких элементов с одинаковым ID, чего не должно быть. Как решение можно обращаться по классу либо иной селектор (например, добавит 
форме `data-form-id="сюда_пишите_id_формы"` и через `document.querySelector("[data-form-id=" + передайте_параметром_id_формы + "]");`

Comment: отлавливать (открывать, показывать, скрывать, всё,  что угодно делать) нужную форму